# Maximum aggregate I/O transfer rate

Tags: io, aggregate, transfer

I just want to check if I calculate it correctly:

A 32-bit computer has two selector channels and one multiplexor channel. Each selector channel supports two magnetic disk and two magnetic tape units.  The multiplexor channel has two line printers, two card readers, and five VDT terminals connected to it.  Assume the following transfer rates.
    Disk drive  700 Kbytes/s
    Magnetic tape drive 200 Kbytes
    Line printer    6.6 Kbytes/s
    Card Reader 1.2 Kbytes/s
    VDT 1 Kbytes/s
Estimate the maximum aggregate I/O transfer rate in this system.

Answer:
700 + 6.6*2 + 1.2*2 + 1*5 = 700+13.2+2.4+5 = 720.6

Answer (score 0):

Only one device at a time can be serviced on a selector channel. Thus,

Maximum Rate = 700 + 700 + 2 * 6.6 + 2 * 1.2 + 5 * 1 = 1420.6 KBytes/sec